# Exterior Render Painting

Tags: painting, exterior, preparation, building, render

We moved into our house 5 years ago which is rendered. We learnt soon after moving in the builders who worked on the house were not very professional. The exterior of the house is rendered and painted but obviously not very well. Paint comes off down to bare render very easily. Unfortunately a year ago a local painter and decorator came and repainted the whole house. We explained that we didn’t think that the original painting/sealing was done correctly. He assured us that he could sort it. Now when it rains the paint bubbles and then the wind blows the paint off. House looks awful like it hasn’t been painted in years. As we have spent a lot of money already and can not get the guy back I will have to do it myself. Do I need to sand all paint off to render then seal then repaint?

Comment: What is "rendering/rendered"?  Maybe it's just not a commonly used term in American English.

Comment: Your last painter is liable for the claims that he made, is it not an option to have them fix it?

Comment: If paint is not adhering putting additional layers will be a waste of $. What is the surface ?  Wood, metal, masonry? If the paint is coming off a pressure washer may be helpful in stripping the old paint, with wood use caution as a pressure washer can damage the wood and this will show through the new paint, hand scraping is usually what I end up with having to do , look up paint scrapers. I would be going after the con that told you they could fix it. At least report him to the contractors board and better business bureau.

Comment: Hi. Render is a masonry coating for exterior walls. (Definition-  a first coat of plaster applied to a brick or stone surface) It is very common in Cornwall where I live. The original paint must have been applied with no mis-cost or sealant so comes off easily. For example stuck some Christmas lights to house with Blue-Tac and when I took lights down it pulled paint off back to render. We have tried several times to get the painter back but he never shows. Trouble now is we have absolutely no trust in him.